# Giving away half of your patent

Tags: ownership

I am looking at getting a patent but am having to go through a third party, which is a college to save money since I am a college student.

I was wondering, if I give half of the patent to the school and I have the other half what are the damages they could potentially do with their half of the patent if they decide to sell it or something else?

If they get half of the patent can they sell their portion to a larger cooperation and if they do would they be able to license it for their own manufacturing purposes? Or would another company have to have the full rights to the patent in order to use it? Also, if they have half of the patent, could they restrict you from doing manufacturing for your product with the other half if the other half decides to sell it?

Also, would they be able to use the other half of the patent to own half of your business by legal rights? Such as use their patent to get capital or a percentage from your company, if you are the one doing all the work with the business?

Comment: This question is really about contracts, not patents. Since we don't have your contract with the college to review, we can't advise you. You really should not rely on Q&A sites and other internet resources for specific legal advice.

Answer (score -1):

> If they get half of the patent can they sell their portion to a larger cooperation and if they do would they be able to license it for their own manufacturing purposes? Or would another company have to have the full rights to the patent in order to use it?

Yes, Yes, and No, as co-owners to a patent **without an agreement** the default is either party can license, sell and manufacture the patent without restriction and without consent of the other parties.

> Also, if they have half of the patent, could they restrict you from doing manufacturing for your product with the other half if the other half decides to sell it?

No as a co-owners to a patent **without an agreement** you may license, sell and manufacture the patent without restriction and without consent of the other parties.

> Also, would they be able to use the other half of the patent to own half of your business by legal rights? Such as use their patent to get capital or a percentage from your company, if you are the one doing all the work with the business?

Co-*inventors* **without an agreement** have no duty to account to each other for license or product revenues

Comment: What kind of agreements would we need for each of these?

Comment: This answer presumes to know what the contract says. We do not know what the contract says so there is no way this is correct.